# sqoop error : Column 'customernumber' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: sqoop

`sqoop import
 --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/classicmodels
 --username root --password cloudera
 --query ' select c.customernumber, c.customername, o.orderdate, o.ordernumber from customers AS c JOIN orders As o ON  c.customernumber = o.customernumber WHERE $CONDITIONS '
--boundary-query 'select min(customernumber), max(customernumber) from customers '
--target-dir /data/info/customerdata/join 
--split-by customernumber ;`

`mysql> describe customers ;
+------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| customerNumber         | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| customerName           | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| contactLastName        | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| contactFirstName       | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| phone                  | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| addressLine1           | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| addressLine2           | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| city                   | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| state                  | varchar(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| postalCode             | varchar(15)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| country                | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| salesRepEmployeeNumber | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| creditLimit            | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+`

`mysql> describe orders ;
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| orderNumber    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| orderDate      | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| requiredDate   | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| shippedDate    | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| status         | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| comments       | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| customerNumber | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+`

Answer (score 0):

Try using tablename.column name syntax for the sql in your query's where clause.

Comment: There is only $CONDITIONS in the where clause.

Comment: Probably the boundary-query is being used in place of the $CONDITIONS. Try using another AS statement in your boundary query:
    --boundary-query 'select min(customernumber), max(customernumber) from customers AS cust'

Answer (score 0):

`sqoop import
 --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/classicmodels
 --username root --password cloudera
 --query 'select customers.customernumber, customers.customername, 
   orders.orderdate, orders.ordernumber FROM customers, orders WHERE 
   customers.customernumber = orders.customernumber AND $CONDITIONS'
--boundary-query 'select min(customernumber), max(customernumber) from customers'
--target-dir /data/info/customerdata/join 
--split-by customers.customernumber ;`

For `--boundary-query`, make sure customernumber should be numeric columns and should not be null.

Comment: Its a numeric column and there is no null value for the column

Comment: great !! you missed table name in `--split-by` clause and therefore you were getting this error.